# Is there a shortcut in Textmate to wrap selection with multiline comment?=begin and =end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate

I want a shortcut in Textmate to wrap the selected text with a ruby multiline comment -- '=begin' and '=end'.
It doesn't look like there is an existing one. Anyone know how to make one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figure it out, mostly by luck. I still wish I could find where the shortcut was defined.
However, it's ⌥⌘/

Answer (score 0):

My bundle always uses the single-line comments, even when I select multiple lines. I'm sure your answer lies somewhere in Bundles > Bundle Editor > Ruby > Comments.